# MVC 4 Membership Can't login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider

I've created an MVC 4 app and for the first time I am trying to use membership.

I have a sql database where I have created the membership tables and using "ASP.NET Configuration" I have selected my providers, added roles and a user.

When I try to login using the login page, I get the error;

> To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an
>   instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider".

I am not using azure nor am i using NuGet.

My config file looks like;

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" name="SqlMembershipProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" name="SqlRoleProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

That's all that was added for me.

My account controller has the following attribute but removing it makes no difference.

```
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
```

and it fails on this line;

```
if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
```

What do I need to do to be able to log users in?

Answer (score 0):

You set [SqlMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx) in config but trying to use [SimpleMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)
Pick one and cofigure your app accordingly.
If you set up db against SimpleMembersip (most frequently one table with UserId, Username and other fields), then change your config as follows and make sure `InitializeSimpleMembershipFilter` looks for userId, username fields as they are set up in your table:

```
<membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
       <clear/>
       <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
    </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider=“SimpleRoleProvider“>
  <providers>
    <add name=“SimpleRoleProvider“ type=“WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData“/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Otherwise, to set up SqlMembershipProvider you may refer to the bottom of this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx

Comment: changing my web.config as shown means that i cannot even get to my login screen.  will try the other

Comment: Same issue when using sqlprovider.  this never used to be this hard

Comment: why cant u get to login screen. what's the exception ?

Comment: @bilalfazlani, the exception is in the question right near the top

Comment: @griegs when switching to SimpleMembershipProvider user SimpleRoleProvider as well, I have updated answer with initialization code

Comment: I made the changes and cannot get to the login page anymore,  never mind, thanks.  might switch to openauth